# Max consecutive time_periods by date and hour

Tags: sql-server

For a particular exercise I am required to find and locate the maximum consecutive/continuous date and time range. The time_period is given in a format `YYYY_MM_DD_hr HH` that I converted into `YYYY-MM-DD-HH:00:00:000` to enable addition and subtraction operations. The data is a forecast that runs from 2014-2039 and I believe I need to basically 'flag' beginning and end of consecutive periods, ie. 2014-01-01-01:00:00:000 to 2014-01-02:00:00:000 would return a value of '1'. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

So far I have something like:

```
SELECT  r1.Report_Day ,
        r1.Report_Hour ,
        r1.report_month ,
        r1.report_year ,
        DATEADD(HOUR, r1.report_hour, CAST(CAST(r1.report_year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(r1.report_month AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(r1.report_day AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)) AS 'NEWDATETIME'
```

Comment: I see you really haven't gone so far :)

Comment: Tell us about the table's structure and give us some sample data

Comment: Sorry I am brand new to this, and had a little trouble pasting a snippet of the table I am working on. I know that this question likely requires an index and a join where one compares the row below it to see whether there is a difference of a day or an hour. Generically, how would you approach this problem. I hope to gain further insight, I'm not looking for someone to hold my hand, I'm stuck on the logic. CHEERS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets make up some test date ranges:

```
DECLARE @DateRangeTable TABLE
(
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO @DateRangeTable
VALUES
( '01-01-2010', '01-31-2010 23:59:00' ),
( '02-01-2010', '02-28-2010 23:59:00' ),
( '03-01-2010', '03-31-2010 23:59:00' ),
( '05-01-2010', '05-31-2010 23:59:00' ),
( '06-01-2010', '06-30-2010 23:59:00' ),
( '01-01-2011', '01-31-2011 23:59:00' ),
( '02-01-2011', '02-28-2011 23:59:00' ),
( '03-01-2011', '03-31-2011 23:59:00' ),
( '04-01-2011', '04-30-2011 23:59:00' ),
( '05-01-2011', '05-31-2011 23:59:00' ),
( '06-01-2011', '06-30-2011 23:59:00' ),
( '01-01-2012', '01-31-2012 23:59:00' ),
( '02-01-2012', '02-28-2012 23:59:00' ),
( '03-01-2012', '03-31-2012 23:59:00' ),
( '04-01-2012', '04-30-2012 23:59:00' ),
( '05-01-2012', '05-31-2012 23:59:00' );
```

Setup to start searching for our periods

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME;
SELECT @StartDate = MIN(StartDate) FROM @DateRangeTable;
```

This part creates a numbers table for all the hours of our range

```
DECLARE @number_of_numbers INT = 100000;

;WITH
a AS (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1),
b AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM a AS x, a AS y),
c AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM b AS x, b AS y),
d AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM c AS x, c AS y),
e AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM d AS x, d AS y),
f AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM e AS x, e AS y),
numbers AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(@number_of_numbers)
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS number
    FROM f
), 
dt as
(
    SELECT dt.CheckHour
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            DATEADD(HOUR, n.number, @StartDate) CheckHour
        FROM numbers n
    ) dt
    INNER JOIN @DateRangeTable drt
        ON dt.CheckHour >= drt.StartDate AND dt.CheckHour <= drt.EndDate
),
t as
(
    SELECT 
        dt.CheckHour,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dt.CheckHour) i
    FROM dt
)
```

We have a couple of CTE expressions above, numbers is numbers table, dt is a list of all the hours based on the date range table, t is just the hours with a rownumber to check against.

```
SELECT 
    d.PeriodStart,
    d.PeriodEnd,
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, d.PeriodStart, d.PeriodEnd) NumOfHours
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        MIN(t.CheckHour) PeriodStart,
        MAX(t.CheckHour) PeriodEnd
    FROM t
    GROUP BY DATEDIFF(HOUR, DATEADD(HOUR, i, 0), t.CheckHour)
) d
```

So the real code is I first get the difference between the hours - the rownumber to group my records into contiguous ranges and then I get the min and max to get the beginning and end and then just diff the hours to get the longest range based on hours, here is the output:

```
PeriodStart               PeriodEnd                NumOfHours
2010-01-01 01:00:00.000   2010-03-31 23:00:00.000  2158
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000   2010-06-30 23:00:00.000  1463
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000   2011-06-30 23:00:00.000  4343
2012-01-01 00:00:00.000   2012-02-28 23:00:00.000  1415
2012-03-01 00:00:00.000   2012-05-31 00:00:00.000  2184
```

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is not very clear but it seems that something on this lines will work:

```
select newdatetime, newdatetime -(select max(newdatetime) 
from yourtable b where b.newdatetime<a.newdatetime) As Period
from yourtable a
order by newdatetime
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Assuming that you created the `NEWDATETIME` column and has the complete datetime value as mentioned in the question,  try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(float, r1_1.NEWDATETIME - MAX(r1_2.NEWDATETIME)) * 24
FROM r1 r1_1
INNER JOIN r1 r1_2 ON r1_2.NEWDATETIME < r1_1.NEWDATETIME
GROUP BY r1_1.NEWDATETIME
```

This gives you all the differences in Hours. To find the maximum value of all:

```
SELECT MAX(hoursDiff) FROM (
SELECT CONVERT(float, r1_1.NEWDATETIME - MAX(r1_2.NEWDATETIME)) * 24 hoursDiff
FROM r1 r1_1
INNER JOIN r1 r1_2 ON r1_2.NEWDATETIME < r1_1.NEWDATETIME
GROUP BY r1_1.NEWDATETIME) dt
```